# Use Multiple Varchar as a parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to create a query that will allow me to use multiple VarChars as a parameter in SSRS.

Here's the code:

```
Declare @CallCodes as VarChar(10)
Set @CallCodes = ('MORC30' , 'Morc60')

;
With Data
AS
    (SELECT 
        VC.[CallCode]
          ,VC.[HospCode]
          ,VC.[HospMastID]
          ,VC.[ClientID]
          ,Row_Number () Over (Partition By HospMastID, VC.ClientID Order By HospMastID, VC.ClientID, GLCode) as Txn
    FROM 
    [RptSys].[dbo].[CSC_VuesionImport_DevDetl] as VC
    Inner Join
    [AVimark_OLTP].[dbo].[Client] as C
    on
    VC.HospMastID = C.HospitalMasterID
    and
    VC.ClientID = C.ClientID
    Inner Join
    [Avimark_OLTP].[dbo].[Patient] as P
    on
    VC.HospMastID = P.HospitalMasterID
    and
    VC.PatientID = P.PatientID
    Inner Join
    [Avimark_OLTP].[dbo].[Treatment] as T
    on
    VC.HospMastID = T.HospitalMasterID
    and
    VC.MastReminder = T.Code
    Where
    VC.CallCode in @CallCodes)
```

This gives an error when I try to run it.  The final output is to allow the end user to choose from a drop down list in an SSRS report I have tried all variations of in or like for the where statement.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error? We can't read neither your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us!**

Comment: Marc,  The errors vary depending whether I use like or in.  I get invalid syntax errors either at the set statement or I get syntax errors at the like statement.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take the Parmaeter in a temporary table marked with #

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(
Callcodes varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES
('MORC30'),
('Morc60')


With Data
AS
(SELECT 
VC.[CallCode]
,VC.[HospCode]
,VC.[HospMastID]
,VC.[ClientID]
,Row_Number () Over (Partition By HospMastID, VC.ClientID Order By HospMastID, VC.ClientID, GLCode) as Txn
FROM 
[RptSys].[dbo].[CSC_VuesionImport_DevDetl] as VC
Inner Join
[AVimark_OLTP].[dbo].[Client] as C
on
VC.HospMastID = C.HospitalMasterID
and
VC.ClientID = C.ClientID
Inner Join
[Avimark_OLTP].[dbo].[Patient] as P
on
VC.HospMastID = P.HospitalMasterID
and
VC.PatientID = P.PatientID
Inner Join
[Avimark_OLTP].[dbo].[Treatment] as T
on
VC.HospMastID = T.HospitalMasterID
and
VC.MastReminder = T.Code
Where
VC.CallCode in (SELECT * FROM #tmp))
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, if not please tell me. Or like mentioned in the comments give a error message

Have a nice day & greets from Switzerland

Etienne

Comment: Etienne, The Parameters are something I want the end user to choose so I can't formalize it fully in a table.  It's part of a report where they choose from a list of codes.

Comment: Ohh I see, so you have a SSRS parameter which the user can set when he opens the report? And is it possible to select more than one value of this list that you mentioned

Comment: Yes- that is the goal.  It works fine with Integer Parameters, just can't seem to get it to work with NVARCHAR parameters.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c02370b5-aeda-47ec-a3a8-43b2ec1e6c26/reporting-services-multi-value-parameter mabey this will help you